# How to get parent thread name from current in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, namespaces

I need to get parent thread name from the "current" `task_struct` in the kernel. 
The `comm` field in `task_struct` is the name given to the thread.

I see that `task_struct` has `parent`, `real_parent`, and `group_leader`.
Accessing the `comm` field in the `task_struct` for any of these does NOT give the name of the parent thread (that clone/vfork'd current thread). Instead I get *systemd* for the parent.

I'm thinking this is because it goes with the *init* namespace. What is the correct way to get the parent name from the "current" thread?

Answer (score 0):

When a thread is created (ie. the `CLONE_THREAD` flag is used), which from the kernel's point of view means a task within the same *thread group*, the parent is not the thread that created it, but the same parent as every other thread in the thread group.  From userspace's point of view, all threads within a process share the same parent, which is the parent of the process.

`.group_leader` is the thread within the process that is the current thread group leader, which is probably closest to what you want (if the `comm` for `.group_leader` is `systemd` then that would tend to indicate that you are looking at a thread within systemd itself).